# Iterate Over Instances of a Class in Python

Tags: python, class, iteration, instance

I've created a class called Equipment, to which I can pass attributes describing the piece of equipment, the sensor type monitoring it, and the data pin that sensor is associated with, for a given instantiation. I then initialize four (arbitrary number) different instances of that class, pass them the attributes that are relevant, and create a list of the variables that represent those instances. From there, I defined a function, based on a for loop, whose job it is to iterate over those instances so that I can pull data from their associated sensors recursively using the contents of the given instance. However, when I go to implement this, I receive a TypeError saying that the Equipment object is not iterable.

To me, this does not make much sense, since I've created instances of the class, which, presumably should exist in memory somewhere and be referenceable using their variable name. Thus, I'm really asking Python to iterate over a list object that contains references to instances of a given class, which shouldn't require the class itself to be iterable. Rather, from my understanding, this should allow for a specific instance to be referenced, and its attributes retrieved.

What am I missing in my current understanding, and how can I start to approach the implementation that I have described/am aiming for?

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
class Equipment:

    def __init__(self, equipmentType, sensor, pin):
        self.equipmentType = equipmentType
        self.sensor = sensor
        self.pin = pin       

dht11Sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11

minus20 = Equipment("Minus 20 Freezer", dht11Sensor, 4)
minus80 = Equipment("Minus 80 Freezer", dht11Sensor, 4)
incubator24 = Equipment("24 Degree Incubator", dht11Sensor, 4)
incubator18 = Equipment("18 Degree Incubator", dht11Sensor, 4)

equipment = [minus20, minus80, incubator24, incubator18]

def recursiveCheck(equipmentList):

    for equipment in equipmentList:
        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(equipment.sensor, equipment.pin)

        if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
            print(f"Your {equipment.equipmentType} is currently {temperature} degrees C and the humidity is {humidity}%")

        else:
            recursiveCheck(equipment)

    time.sleep(5)
    recursiveCheck(equipmentList)

recursiveCheck(equipment)
```

Comment: in the line `recursiveCheck(equipment)` (inside the `else`) you are calling the function on one of the `Element` objects in the list, and in turn doing `for equipment in equipmentList:` where that object is now serving as `equipmentList`. The question is why are you even using a function? Wouldn't a loop suffice?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the error. Take note that your code as shown cannot run due to a syntax error (unindented else block).

Comment: Fyi, the line after the else isn't indented.

Comment: Line after the else is a formatting error here only. It's as expected in my actual code. Sorry about that, I will edit it now.

Comment: Tomerikoo, your (inside ...) clarification has helped me understand more what you were getting at, sorry for the misunderstanding. Is there a way to do what I want while avoiding that?

Comment: Don't use a function. Simply use the loop. It is not clear exactly what is the purpose of the recursive calls so that is as much advise as I can give

Comment: The recursivity was a solution to the sensor returning None values. Unfortunately, that results in my passing an object into a function meant to iterate over a list in the current implementation, so now I'm trying to figure out how to get that to happen by passing some index of the list where it references the location of the equipment that returned None, that way it doesn't get skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you are calling the method recursively and hence in the second round you call it with the object itself instead of the list!

in the for-loop this line:

```
recursiveCheck(equipment)
```

you are calling the function with one Equipment object and when it runs, it tries to do the for-loop on this object which is not your list!
you probably wanted your code to be like this:

```
class Equipment:

    def __init__(self, equipmentType, sensor, pin):
        self.equipmentType = equipmentType
        self.sensor = sensor
        self.pin = pin       

dht11Sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11

minus20 = Equipment("Minus 20 Freezer", dht11Sensor, 4)
minus80 = Equipment("Minus 80 Freezer", dht11Sensor, 4)
incubator24 = Equipment("24 Degree Incubator", dht11Sensor, 4)
incubator18 = Equipment("18 Degree Incubator", dht11Sensor, 4)

equipment = [minus20, minus80, incubator24, incubator18]

def recursiveCheck(equipmentList):

    for equipment in equipmentList:
        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(equipment.sensor, equipment.pin)

        if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
            print(f"Your {equipment.equipmentType} is currently {temperature} degrees C and the humidity is {humidity}%")

        else:
            recursiveCheck(equipmentList)

    time.sleep(5)
    recursiveCheck(equipmentList)

recursiveCheck(equipment)
```

so to recap, the first time that your code runs, it runs ok and doesn't encounter any error (you could fact-check it with a simple print or a counter), the failure happens when your code goes to else statement in the for-loop because you are trying to pass an object instead of a list!

===
update:

so if you want to start the list from a given index when it fails you could do this:

```
class Equipment:

    def __init__(self, equipmentType, sensor, pin):
        self.equipmentType = equipmentType
        self.sensor = sensor
        self.pin = pin       

dht11Sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11

minus20 = Equipment("Minus 20 Freezer", dht11Sensor, 4)
minus80 = Equipment("Minus 80 Freezer", dht11Sensor, 4)
incubator24 = Equipment("24 Degree Incubator", dht11Sensor, 4)
incubator18 = Equipment("18 Degree Incubator", dht11Sensor, 4)

equipment = [minus20, minus80, incubator24, incubator18]

def recursiveCheck(equipmentList, index=0):

    for i in in range(index, len(equipmentList)):
        equipment = equipmentList[i]
        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(equipment.sensor, equipment.pin)

        if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
            print(f"Your {equipment.equipmentType} is currently {temperature} degrees C and the humidity is {humidity}%")

        else:
            recursiveCheck(equipmentList, i)
            return;

while True:
    recursiveCheck(equipment)
    time.sleep(5)
```

so I have made your function non-recursive because if I didn't do that it would have became a mess in runtime, and it might have gotten hard to follow where it is going!!

Comment: Hi Saeed, thanks for your input. You are both correct and a little off. I have the recursive check set up like that because the sensors will return None values sometimes, so I'm using that to filter. I see how that can be causing problems though! How would I pass the object it was returning None for as an index within the equipmentList? That way I can pass the full list again but force it to start where it was before

Comment: sorry I got a little confused :). are you saying that this is actually your problem and you want to know how to start over from an index in the list? or are you saying the problem is something else?

Comment: Your insight was totally correct and extremely helpful in conceptualizing the problem, but it's funny because the problem arises from my solution to another problem -- i.e. that the sensor will sometimes return None, rather than temp/humidity values. The idea was, if it isn't a none value, then we're all good, print the results. However, if it is None, that's no good, try again, but on the same piece of equipment (rather than starting the whole list over). Does that make a little bit more sense?

Comment: yes sure. I will post an update to fix this problem too for you shortly :)

Comment: Saeed, thank you so much! You and @Tomerikoo were spot on and caught the major issue immediately, and I'm very grateful. I've learned a lot just now, in terms of bugs to watch out for when working with this kind of function (incidentally, this kind of learning experience is part of why I chose to do it this way). Hopefully there is a solution that will allow for that kind of recursive filtering, while still accommodating the recursive screening over the whole list :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206312/discussion-between-ejkiely-and-saeed-foroughi).